# flex: a repeater with Dataprovider flickers a bit when there is an update

Tags: apache-flex, repeater, dataprovider

i have the following code:
         `<mx:Repeater id="user" dataProvider="{data}">
                    <mx:VBox styleName="repeaterVBox">
                    <mx:Text text="{user.currentItem.a}. {user.currentItem.b}" styleName="repeaterText"/>

                    <mx:Text text="{user.currentItem.c}"  styleName="repeaterText"/>
                    <mx:Text text="{user.currentItem.d}" styleName="repeaterText"/>
                </mx:VBox>
         </mx:Repeater>`

the dataProvider 'data' updated itself every 3 seconds, so every 3 seconds that is a flicker of some sort, i see for a really short time an empty area and then it gets redrawn again. is there a way to make the update somewhat faster ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use repeaters, they are poorly implemented.  try to use itemrenderers